# Пример реализации классов в UML для C++ кода

Tags: uml, c++

Вот что написано: реализация – это способ показать наследование интерфейса в UML. Когда мы говорим, что класс A реализует интерфейс B, это значит, что мы можем обращаться к A методами B. Покажите, пожалуйста, как это выглядит в C++ коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С ++ коде выглядит примерно так:

Клас интерфейс:

```
class IInterfaceExample
{
public:
   virtual void Method1() = 0;
   virtual void Method2() = 0;
};
```

Класс, который унаследовал этот интерфейс и реализовал его:

```
  class CSomeClass : public IInterfaceExample
  {
  public:
      // some public members

  private:
   // some private members

   void Method1()
   {
      // do something
   }
   void Method2()
   {
       // do something  
   }
 };
```

Объявление интерфейса, с помощью которого будем обращаться к функциям, реализованных в классе-потомке:

```
   IInterfaceExample *InterfecePtr = new CSomeClass;
```

**Обновление**

Так, виртуальный класс только описывает интерфейс (но не реализует).
Может существовать несколько потомков, каждый из которых по-своему будет реализовывать интерфейс.

InterfecePtr будет обращаться к той реализации, которую ей присвоят, 
в данном случае  CSomeClass.

Такое явление называется динамическим полиморфизмом.

Интерфейс - набор правил для полного взаимодействия, проще говоря, в нашем случае это набор функций, каждая из которых отвечает за какое-то действие.

Интерфейс это просто набор функций, без реализации, поэтому один интерфейс реализовывать другой не может.

Один интерфейс может только наследовать другой.
Например, есть интерфейс, "создание" в котором есть функции "бегать" и "ходить".
А есть унаследованный от него интерфейс "собака" и "кошка".
В интерфейсе "собака" унаследованные функции "бегать" и "ходить" и добавлена функция "лаять".

А в интерфейсе "кошка" унаследованные функции "бегать" и "ходить" и добавлена функция "мьявкать".

Тогда уже интерфейсы собака и кошка реализуютса в определенных классах.

Comment: Это значит, что чистый виртуальный класс это интерфейс для будующих потомков. Правильно я понял?

Comment: 
Один интерфейс может только наследовать другой.
Например, есть интерфейс, "создание" в котором есть функции "бегать" и "ходить".  
А есть унаследованный от него интерфейс "собака" и "кошка".
В интерфейсе "собака" унаследованные функции "бегать" и "ходить" и добавлена функция "лаять".

А в интерфейсе "кошка" унаследованные функции "бегать" и "ходить" и добавлена функция "мьявкать".

Тогда уже интерфейсы собака и кошка реализуютса в определенных классах.